# Populating C# combobox from SQL and restrict results based on choice

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, combobox

I am binding some data from a SQL table into a C# `ComboBox`. What I want to achieve is the following:

Say we have 3 tables in SQL

1. `Room` (Bedroom, Bathroom, Hall)
2. `Stuff` (Bed, Bath, Wardrobe)
3. `StuffProperty` (DoubleBed, HotRunningWater, Clothes).

My goal is to restrict the second and the third `ComboBox` values, based on the choice of the first `ComboBox`, i.e:

The first `ComboBox` contains Bedroom, Bathroom, Hall. If the user chooses Bathroom, the second `ComboBox` contains only Bath and not Bed or Wardrobe and the third `ComboBox` only contains HotRunningWater, not DoubleBed or Clothes

How can I send a query back to SQL without pushing a button, 'live'?

Also, should I use Stored procedures to map Room, Stuff and StuffProperty values together and invoke them in C# code (this is what I would prefer)? Or should I write the whole filtering stuff in C# (for example using switches)?

Really clueless on this one and not even sure if there's any way to 'inform' the SQL of a recent choice without pushing a button. The columns I used are only to illustrate the problem.

Also, I'm aware this question has been asked here a couple of times, but all I found were VB code and I need it to be sorted with a Stored Procedure and C#, or C# only.

Comment: Is this winforms? wpf?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to hook onto an event of the combobox, most likely selectedIndexChanged or similar. This is how you get the "live" effect. You would need to hook onto the event of the first combobox and then populate the second.

Then in the event of the second you need to populate the third.

How you go about this using metro wizard I am not to sure but hopefully with a gameplan you can find the required code.

Comment: ahh okay - there's actually a selectedIndexChanged property. I make it call a Stored Procedure - all I need to figure now what does that should contain, i.e. how to map one value from a table to another in a different table. I'm actually considering using a primary key from one table and get the same key (as a foreign this time) from the other one, using INNER JOIN. I might not be on the right track though - we'll see. Thanks for your help.