# C# combobox value to pass to SQL parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, combobox

This question is related to my previous one here:

[Populating C# combobox from SQL and restrict results based on choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40764616/populating-c-sharp-combobox-from-sql-and-restrict-results-based-on-choice)

hoping to get more attention. Given a combobox from which I'd like to pass the value. On the SelectedIndexChange property I put a method, which calls a Stored Procedure from SQL.

```
SqlCommand command;

command.Parameters.Add("@someparameter", combobox1.GetItemText(combobox1.SelectedItem));

command.CommandText = "StoredProcedure1";

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Well, it takes no effect. Anyone to point out what I'm doing wrong/missing? Thank you

Comment: Removing essential parts of your code doesn't help to understand what's going on here. Do you have created the SqlCommand with a proper sql text? Do you have linked it to the connection? Is the connection open? Did you set the CommandType property?. And finally. What is the value of this expression _combobox1.GetItemText(combobox1.SelectedItem));_

Comment: Seeing a SqlCommand object in the same code as a comboBox object makes my eyes burn.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658109.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

You have an SQL command and a parameter. You execute the command, but into what connection?

It's like me starting my engine, but I haven't actually got the rest of the car to drive. I can turn it on, but without a car I can't drive.

You can fix this by doing something like this:

`SqlCommand newCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT @someParameter from DATABASE", conn);`

Notice the `, conn` at the end of the above command. This allows you to use a method such as `ExecuteNonQuery()`, and the command knows which connection to use for its query.

Comment: Thanks - I might not get you totally, but the added line didn't help much. This is how to code looks now:

SqlCommand command;

command.Parameters.Add("@someparameter", combobox1.GetItemText(combobox1.SelectedItem));

command.CommandText = "StoredProcedure1";

SqlCommand newCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT @someparameter from DATABASE", connection);

newCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

tried to change the DATABASE to the table name, didn't help either. sorry for the dumb questions...