# Retrieving and assigning a combobox value to a stored procedure parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, combobox

[Problem from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40769430/c-sharp-combobox-value-to-pass-to-sql-parameter)...still couldn't get sorted.

Have gone through a million post and videos but couldn't find the one that points out what I'm doing wrong. I basically want to retrieve and assign a combobox's value, and send it to an SQL stored procedure's parameter. I was blamed not to provide code enough yesterday so here's a bit more detailed.

```
SqlConnection _connection;
SqlCommand _command;

_connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=someserver;Initial Catalog=sometable;Integrated Security=True");

_connection.Open();

_command = _connection.CreateCommand();
_command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

private void SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        _command.CommandText = "someprocedurename";
        _command.Parameters.Add("@someparameter", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = combobox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

        _command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    finally
    {
        _connection.Close();
    }
}
```

What happens: when I select the item in the combobox, it first automatically pops up the error message, then it shows the item in the box, but apparently the value of it is not getting passed to `@someparameter`, or at least the stored procedure is not getting triggered. The stored procedure, written and tested in SQL, works - the problem is in the C# code. I'm aware this might be a lame question for lots of pros out there, but please considerate I've done my research. Please be as specific as you can - not here to get criticized but to improve my newbie skills. Thanks.

C#, Windows Forms

EDIT:

catch block was amended as Sir Henry recommended.

[This is what I see now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcruG.png)

and after moving _connection.Open(); into the try block,

[this is what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oc2ow.png)

Pretty much wtf...

EDIT 2:

it seems the problem is gone, thanks to Sir Henry. All I need to figure out now is how to populate the second combobox, based on the stored procedure that was called by the value of the first combobox. This is how the code looks like now:

```
private void SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (SqlConnection _connection =
                new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=someserver;Initial Catalog=sometable;Integrated Security=True"))

            try
            {

                _connection.Open();

                SqlCommand _command  = new SqlCommand("someprocedurename", _connection);

                _command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                _command.Parameters.Add("@someparameter", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = combobox1.SelectedValue.ToString();

                _command.ExecuteNonQuery();

/* i guess this is the part where i should "inform" combobox2 about the
 result of the stored procedure, based on combobox1. have no idea though,
 how it could be done. maybe i need a dataset? clueless. just to be clear:
if value "a" was selected in combobox1, i want to populate combobox2 with 
the value "1". if value "b" was selected in combobox1, i want to populate
combobox2 with the value "2". etc. */

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: First you should find out exception. I guess it may be problem with command or connection. For this  rewrite catch block catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }  then post exception in your question

Comment: sorry for the late reply - was off on Friday but now I'm back and have done the necessary changes. Please see the EDIT in the question. thanks

Comment: Your problem is _connection.Close(); in finally block. Connection usually  two types global or local (unit of work). Global is always open and it is bad practice  to close it in local method. Local has initialized in methods body and  you should close connection or use using() {} insructon

Comment: Event has been invoked several times. And first call is closing conection. Second is falling with exception

Comment: thanks mate. it seems partially solving the problem but still not entirely. mind to have a look at EDIT2 if you had a second. appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `combobox1.SelectedValue.ToString();` instead of `combobox1.SelectedItem.ToString();`

One of the reasons for this kind of issue is you're binding an entity to the ComboBox. Can you share the code of data binding to the ComboBox?

Comment: I tried it just now but to no avail, same problem. Data binding is auto-generated code by Metro framework, you basically provide a datasource/table for the combobox and it is done. Thanks for trying helping though.

Comment: Can you place a breakpoint at the line and debug the properties in ComboBox. May shed some light.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
SqlConnection _connection;
SqlCommand _command;

_connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=someserver;Initial Catalog=sometable;Integrated Security=True");

_connection.Open();

_command = _connection.CreateCommand();
_command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

private void SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        _command.CommandText = "someprocedurename";
        _command.Parameters.Add("@someparameter", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = combobox1.SelectedValue.ToString();

        _command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
 finally
 {
    _connection.Close();
  }
}
```

Comment: sooo....how exactly this solution differs from mine? could you please point the changes you made? every single line is the same as in the question and that's unfortunately not working. thanks